# Website Coding & Chrome Slow Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm putting together this site [www.datingjapan.co](http://www.datingjapan.co) and I've noticed the scrolling in chrome only is very slow and jumpy.

I would have to assume this is from my coding style.

Would anyone have any advise as to how I could do this better and why I might be impacting chromes performance.

Note: I have a fair amount of images coming down (which I improve later) but I don't think this would be the scroll issue.

I'm using a fair amount of jquery $(document).on() piece of code to link events but not sure if this would slow it down.

any advice would be great... thx

Comment: did you bind anything to the scroll event?

Comment: If you have a lot of `$(document).on()` handlers assigned then it can slow it down.  Can you not use a closer selector than document, say a containing element?

Comment: scroll event - there is a hidden chat panel that popups later if required.. could these kinds of pending event handlers impact the scroll in google? I assume they are poor coding as they just take resources...